# Sqlite3: Select column items based on the value of different column items

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

Here is my table, it shows questions based on topics of a given subject:[image]

As you can see all the subject and topics are the same at the moment, I will add more as time goes by, this is just a test.

Anyway, I know that I can select a question from the table (named questions) using:

```
select question from questions
```

However I want to only select the questions that come from a certain topic, for example I want to only select questions which come from the topic 'The Fundamentals of Chemistry'. (I'm aware I spelt fundamentals wrong in the database).

I'm using this for a flask website too, thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from question where topic='The Fundamentals of Chemistry'
```

this should help

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT question FROM questions WHERE topic="The Fundementals of Chemistry"`

I guess...